# Find average between two date columns for specific rows in a group

Tags: mysql, average, datediff

I have a table with 2 dates in it and a product, and I need to get the average days difference between them considering just the last 3 rows for each product.

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(date2, date1)) FROM table WHERE product = 121
```

This gives me the average of all the date differences for product 121

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(date2, date1)) FROM table WHERE product = 121 LIMIT 3
```

Still gives me the average off all the records, ignoring the LIMIT argument.

Also when I try a different approach, it also does ignore the last argument and shows the average off all the rows.

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(date2, date1)) FROM table WHERE product =121 && date1 > 2015-01-01
```

Any idea on how to fix this or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your qualifier for the last three rows? The latest 3 `date1`s? latest 3 `date2`s? Something else?

Answer (score 4):

When you have problems like this, I recommend breaking it up and putting it back.

Before doing any calculations, you know that you need the last three rows for each product. So, if you want for example the rows with the latest `date2` you can select them by doing the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE product = 121
ORDER BY date2 DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

That will select the 3 latest rows you want. Then, just use that as a subquery to preform the aggregation. This way, the calculations are only made on the rows you are concerned with:

```
SELECT product, AVG(DATEDIFF(date2, date1))
FROM(
   SELECT product, date1, date2
   FROM myTable
   WHERE product = 121
   ORDER BY date2 DESC
   LIMIT 3) tempTable;
```

Comment: Not a problem. If this remains the answer that helps you, feel free to select the checkmark next to the answer. This will help future readers see which answer solved your problem.

Comment: Not only a good answer, but a great explanation of how to tackle the problem-solving aspect. Nice job @McAdam331

Comment: Thank you @degenerate I really appreciate that.